# How can I make ensure upon clicking the logout button that the user gets redirected to the home component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-hooks, material-ui

I can't figure out how I can navigate the user to the `Home` component when logging out.  The API works fine as I've tested it out.

However, I'm not sure how to use the `logout` method in the current context in order for the user to logout successfully and return to the `Home` component.

The current behavior is incorrect as when I click on `Logout`, the `Grid` component goes blank instead of redirecting to `Home` component.  How can I fix this?

Here'a App.js:

```
const App = () => {
return (
    <>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <ProtectedRoute path="/gallery" component={Grid} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </>
   );
}
```

Here's Navbar.js:

```
import { Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const settings = ['Profile', 'Account', 'Gallery', 'Logout'];
let authToken  = localStorage.getItem('token');



const settingsSelection = (settings) => {
    switch (settings) {
        case "Logout":
            return "/";
    }
};

const logout = () => {
        const headers = {
            "Accept": 'application/json',
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
        };

        const data = "";

        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/logout', data, {headers})
            .then(resp => {
                localStorage.removeItem('token');
                history.push('/');
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}


{settings.map((setting) => (
        <MenuItem key={setting} onClick={handleCloseUserMenu}>
            <Typography
                textAlign="center"
                component={RouterLink}
                to={settingsSelection(setting)}
                // onClick={logout()}
            >
                {setting}
            </Typography>
        </MenuItem>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **useNavigate** instead of useHistory.

```js
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const navigate = useNavigate();

const logout = () => {
        const headers = {
            "Accept": 'application/json',
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
        };

        const data = "";

        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/logout', data, {headers})
            .then(resp => {
                localStorage.removeItem('token');
                navigate("/");
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

Comment: `useNavigate` is for React Router version 6.  I'm using 5 so this doesn't apply to me.

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.